# I can not get RejectedExecutionException with ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice, executor

I create scheduller for test handling of RejectedExecutionException:

```
@Component
public class TestScheduler {

    private final TestService testService;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public TestScheduler(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10L)
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
        executorService.execute(testService::print);
    }
}
```

And service with delay 70 seconds:

```
@Component
public class TestService {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("print start");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(70);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("print end");
    }
}
```

I wait next logic:

1. Scheduler call `executorService.execute(testService::print)` 5 times
2. Each `testService::print` will execute 70 seconds
3. When `execute` method will call sixth time I get `RejectedExecutionException`

But I not get Exception. I have this logs:

```
test
print start
2018-10-22 11:26:45.543  INFO 5960 --- [           main] c.e.s.SchedullerExceptionsApplication    : Started SchedullerExceptionsApplication in 0.661 seconds (JVM running for 1.108)
test
print start
test
print start
test
print start
test
print start
test
...
70 seconds print test
```

**EDIT**

In real project I have this code:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100, new CustomizableThreadFactory("SendRequestExecutor-"));
    }

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
public void sendReady() {
    try {
        List<Message> messages = messageService.findReadyToSend();
        for (Message message : messages) {
            message.setStatus(IN_PROCESS);
            Message savedMessage = messageService.save(message);
            executorService.execute(() -> sendRequestService.send(savedMessage.getGuid()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("handle: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

does it mean that this code is wrong? because that can happen so I will change entity to status `IN_PROCESS` and when try execute - if `executorService` full I do not get exception and `executorService` not execute my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects involved when defining an executor.

1. **The number of threads that will be used by the executor.** This puts a limit on the number of concurrent tasks the executor can run. This is what you are setting via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)`.
2. **The size of the underlying task submission queue.** This puts a limit on the number of tasks the underlying queue can store until it will throw an exception. The executor created by `newFixedThreadPool` uses an unbounded queue, therefore you do not get an exception.

You can achieve your desired behavior by creating your own executor service as follows and submitting 11 tasks to it (5 to use all the threads, 5 to fill the underlying task queue and 1 to overflow it).

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 
                       5, 
                       2000L, 
                       TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
                       new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5, true), 
                       new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

Comment: I eddit question. Look please

Comment: @ip696 The code is not *wrong*. That executor service definition uses an unbounded task queue, so you get no exceptions. If you want to get overflow exceptions, change how the executor is created.

Comment: aaa, it seems, I understood that you mean) that is at me a pool from 5 threads but queue unlimited. and when the pool is full - new threads put to the queue and when they are finished, they are replaced from the queue? then in this case, if my sheduler will overtake the executor very much, I can only get memory overflow(executor  queue will very large)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, tasks are added to the (unbounded) task queue and wait for available threads. It can only fail with out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

`RejectedExecutionException` will be thrown you you **overflow tasks queue** (and that is unbound right now) while you expect it to be thrown when you schedule more tasks (put it into probably unbounded queue) then you have workers - thats nonsens as this is kind of purpose of worker - to build queue and execute from it.

To test error handling, either mock your executor and throw exception on task submit (preferable), or use limited, bounded, non blocking queue as a backing queue for your executor.

Using mock is the most easy way to do this.